# Can help me to make a MACRO with copying, colouring and hyperlink(ing?)

Tags: vba, colors, hyperlink, copy, rgb

Good morning everybody

I m getting my self into my own new project for my self and for that I analyse 54 products. I would wish to have each product in a single sheet and to a second sheet for more details. So I was checking a little in google and found EXCEL VBA and I tried my self to get a formula but I don t get it and what I need requires professional knowledge. Even if it fascinating to do so I have no time to study computer language now.

Would it be possible to get all my steps in one VBA formula ? I imagined that I change each day the cell location in VBA and apply !

So here are the details, let s take it easy with this 54 products and days and sheets, I m having trouble to focus, let s imaging together I take the data of one product in one day and then this should get squeezed in VBA with 54 products, lol ?

Would it be possible to get a formula that can copy 3 cells from one sheet to another sheet, then add words in the 4. cell bellow and depending if 1. cell is above zero or below zero than to change the “fill colour” in the 4. Cell to RGB 0, 135, 60 / RGB 235, 15, 41. So we not finished yet to make it perfect, so now the 4. Cell should be copied in a new sheet for the summary of course with the colour in one cell and that cell must be hyperlinked to the 4. Cell of the previous sheet and back hyperlinked to the new cell in the new sheet.

Can all this work in on VBA formula ? Can I get the formula for to work on one product and I would then just copy the formula and add the names of each product and I would have to change the cell location manually in the formula as the data is an ongoing collection of days and days ?

I go shopping now, me head needs a fresh idea :)

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to understand without seeing data directly.
But if I understood correctly, I would suggest to create a Pivot Report from the main sheet of products and their data, later apply conditional formatting on the Pivot results...

If you need macros, - record your steps using macros recorder and try to reproduce.
You will most likely run into problem like auto-adjust range for the pivot data connection...
Solution will depend on the format (Table or Raw data) is on the main sheet.

Comment: I have tried with the macro but where it gets for me really complicated is when i come to the part where i want to change the colour in the cell when the other cell is above or below zero with the corresponding color. To be honest i have no idea how Macro can record this ! but i m ok for the rest but i need that middle piece. It must be possible to do it all with VBA because i can see most elements on my searches on google but not all and if one element is missing or wrong the Macro will not work :(

Comment: Good morning, i managed to take pictures. So what i done is i took the picture in the process of doing one product for one week but i cannot introduce each day with notes because it would make unreadable so what i done is i filled in the cells only with the end result and wich should light up how the sheet will evaluate. I should really have replaced the names of SHEET 2 and 3 to Product 1 and Product 1 summary. I hope i m helpful with this, if not please ask me and i will answer

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQUsQ.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVOwY.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Su2DQ.jpg

Comment: If I understood correctly, - 

Sheet1 has list of all products + some data in columns A:EX (would be nice to see it as there is no way to automate things if you do not know what you are automating).
MACRO should generate 2 sheets based on Sheet1 per each product it has + extract 4 values:  Weekday, + three types of figures (you should describe which figures from what location, or which condition figures must match to get extracted).

Comment: Row 13 - Bottom text in the Product sheet  should have conditional formatting and linked to Product Summary Sheet, which should contain the same text and formatting as Row13 and linked back to Row 13 cell?

Comment: So at the end, 54 products, will become 108 sheets to go through manually.

Comment: Hello i just see i dowloaded one picture twice, strange i was sure i made them correctly. I changed the text also on the pics to make it more easy to understand, i think now it should be easy. Hope i don t break any rule so :(. STEP 1 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK2TB.jpg
STEP 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rd6e.jpg
STEP 3: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zD8QC.jpg

Comment: 108 sheets, correct, yes :)

Comment: I tried conditional formatting but when i copied from Row 13 to Row 13 it did not copy the color with. So i give up and i thought to bring in the macro if possible. But conditional formatting works in SHEET 2 E13 and then i pulled the cell to the right side and it did automatically conditional formatting for the coming data

Comment: Hello i agree with u but i m lost on see here what u wrote:  + three types of figures (you should describe which figures from what location, or which condition figures must match to get extracted).

Comment: The updated picture is clear enough, so now it is clear where the figures come from.
Just a suggestion, 
instead of copy pasting, - you actually can link the excel to the website of you use and get data from it automatically...
Go to window >Data >From Web>Enter Website>CHOOSE part of Website (usually table) to import... 
Test it, - if you like this, we can move forward from this part

Comment: Wich one ? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5iVBb.png

Comment: HTML is the same as Web

Comment: When i click on HTML then my EXCEL folder Opens. I m using OFFICE 365 Version 16.57 on my Mac. I have tried them 4 and non of them is redirecting me on CHROME. The plan was to be redirected on CHROME, right ?

Comment: Sadly, MAC excel is not my cup of tea... And even the macros coding I know, may not work on it properly....
as per data from web... mayb this one will help you out
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kG2xFbiFNFg&ab_channel=rburtch3

Comment: Hello: This Video was very good but somehow i cannot apply it for my Mac :(. But i have no problems to copy the Data every Day from the Internet. Perhaps later will work. U think the Macro is not gone work ?, Let s have a try a make it work should we ?? :)

Comment: Heloo, should i give up here in the Forum you mean ? As u mentioned u doubt the Macro would work on my Mac. ?

Comment: Hi, it will work, - but sadly I am not experienced in coding for MAC...
You can try to create a new post, based on our conversation, - so more experienced guys will easily pick up what you need.
At the moment, - you main post is very unclear...

Comment: and would Strongly advise to learn how to import data from web, so you would start from correctly saved raw data.